# WiX failing to install as 64 bit

Tags: wix, windows-services, 32bit-64bit

I have a Windows service installed via WiX built .msi. I am trying to install the service as 64 bit, but am failing miserably for some reason.

Actual `.wixproj` file has the needed build attributes:

- `<Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">x64</Platform>`
- `<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|x64' ">`

The `.wxs` file has the necessary information:

- `<Package ... Platform = x64 />`
- installs into the `Program Files` folder
- all my `Component` elements have `Win64=yes`

The project containing the service .exe builds as `AnyCPU`

The environment (Windows Server '08 R2) is 64 bit.

The actual build, of both the .exe and the `.wixproj` both go fine.

The install goes fine.

But when I go to view the actual service via Task Manager it is tagged with `*32`.
Is there something that I am missing here that is preventing my application from installing as a 64 bit process/causing it to install as 32 bit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not because of WiX.  This is because you built the program as AnyCPU.  See this answer for more details.

[Build platform target AnyCPU EXE still shows 32bit header in 64bit machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27830701/build-platform-target-anycpu-exe-still-shows-32bit-header-in-64bit-machine)

Comment: Arghh, of course it is the simple answer! Thanks a million.